# I'm getting a strange SMTP error when sending mail with gmail, even though the code is supposed to work properly

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib

I get the error "raise SMTPResponseException(code, message)
smtplib.SMTPResponseException: (334, b'UGFzc3dvcmQ6')"

The program initially runs smoothly but after a few seconds it crashes and gives this error. I'm trying to send stock price alerts to my email with the program. According to pycharm the error is in line 43 (print("completed")). I would tremendously appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

```
import os
import smtplib
import imghdr
import time
from email.message import EmailMessage

import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

EMAIL_ADDRESS = os.environ.get("email@gmail.com")
EMAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("password")

msg = EmailMessage()

yf.pdr_override()
start = dt.datetime(2018, 12, 1)
now = dt.datetime.now()

stock = "TSLA"
TargetPrice = 180

msg["Subject"] = "Alert on " + stock
msg["From"] = EMAIL_ADDRESS
msg["To"] = "elogeedotcom@gmail.com"

alerted = False

while 1:
    df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock, start, now)
    currentClose = df["Adj Close"][-1]

    condition = currentClose > TargetPrice
    if(condition and alerted==False):
        alerted = True
        message = stock + " has reached the target price of " + str(TargetPrice) +\
        "\nCurrent Price: "+ str(currentClose)
        msg.set_content(message)

        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465) as smtp:
            smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
            smtp.send_message(msg)
            print("completed")

    else:
        print("no new alerts")

    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: The error is surely in the line above, `smtp.send_message(msg)`. Also, SMTP response 334 is a "server challenge", and that text is the "base64 encoded challenge" ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMTP_server_return_codes)). It seems like the server is sending a valid response, but `smtplib` isn't expecting that for some reason.

Comment: May be related to https://bugs.python.org/issue27820

Comment: According to https://stackabuse.com/how-to-send-emails-with-gmail-using-python/, you need to send an `.ehlo()` to `smtp` before continuing. And there's some other setup required. Did you do any of those required things? Does it work if you follow that guide? Or [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/send-mail-from-your-gmail-account-using-python), which has you do `starttls()`?